# Allowing a typescript type to be either an object type or a primitive type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm looking to create a type that allows the use of any and all class features of a custom class, as well as primitive operations. For some background (and because I know this is generally bad practice) the project this is for is a compiler. Basically, the goal of the custom class is to define the primitive operations of the other programming language (i.e. charAt() in typescript becomes get() in the target language). I would love to just be able to define a type that has all these operations, but this fails when the custom class shares any properties with the primitive type in typescript.

For example:

```
export class MyList<T> extends ... {
   map(callback: (index: number, current: T) => MyType): MyList<any> {...}
}

export class MyString extends MyClass {
   public includes(toFind: MyType) {...}
   public length() {...}
}

// should be either MyString or string and we don't care which
export type MyType = MyString | string | (MyString & string);

// compiles:
const myStringTest1 = new MyString();
const myStringTest2 = new MyString();

myStringTest2.includes('test');

// doesn't compile:
const myListTest = new MyList<MyType>();
myListTest.map((a, b) => b.length());
```

I know that I could get around this by explicitly telling the compiler what the object is supposed to be (i.e. in the code above using `(b as MyString).length()`) but I would like to avoid using any and all explicit casts and instead allow either type to be used and accessed freely.

This is all to say, I would like to define a type that is treated as BOTH a string and a MyString at the same time, and takes all duplicate class signatures from the object type and not the primitive type.

I would also like to reiterate that this is a compiler, and is NOT supposed to actually contain code that 'runs' per se, but is supposed to be compiled down into a lower level language.

EDIT: Requests for actual implementable code:

```js
export class MyNumber {
    value: MyNumberType;
    test(n: MyNumberType) {return n;}
}

export type MyNumberType = number | MyNumber | (MyNumber & number);

const myNumber1 = new MyNumber();
const myNumber2 = new MyNumber();
myNumber1 === myNumber2;
myNumber1.value === 2;
myNumber1.value < 2;
myNumber1.value > 2;
myNumber1.test(myNumber2);

// string:

export class MyString {
    value: MyStringType; 
    public toLowerCase() {return true }
    public includes(toFind: MyStringType) { return true; }
    public replace(toReplace: MyStringType, toReplaceWith: MyStringType) { return this }
    public length(): number { return 0; }
}

export type MyStringType = (MyString & string) | string | MyString; // should be either MyString or string

const myStringTest1 = new MyString();
const myStringTest2 = new MyString();

myStringTest1.includes('test');
myStringTest1.includes(myStringTest2);

myStringTest1.value + '';

export class MyList<T> {
    map(callback: (index: number, current: T) => any): MyList<any> { return this; }
}

const x = new MyList<MyStringType>();
x.map((a, b) => b.length())
```

When you implement this code you'll see compiler errors for the number comparisons using `<` and `>` and for the .length() call. I'm looking to define `MyStringType` and `MyNumberType` so this code compiles.

Comment: Why is `length` not a getter?

Comment: Very confused by what's going on here... could you make it a [mre] without undeclared types/values or pseudocode so we can at least play around with it without having to fix errors you're not experiencing?

Comment: "define a type that is treated as BOTH a string and a MyString at the same time" you'll need a `class implements String` then

Comment: Length is not a getter because that is how it is implemented in the target language that the code is being compiled to.

`class implements String` doesn't work because of mismatched object methods. There are functions with the same name of the MyString class that differ from the Typescript String class

Comment: But you can't have something in JavaScript which is *both* a primitive and an object type.  You can use unions, but then you need to discriminate the union before any operation that depends on it being the primitive.  You can write `typeof b === "string" ? b.length : b.length()`, for example.  As for your number thing I guess it can be a huge linked list so you need a recursive function or other loop.   See [this playground link](//tsplay.dev/WYyvrW).  That's the best I can imagine doing here. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer. If not, then what am I missing?

Comment: I understand that that I can get around it through force casting or ternary casting, I'm just looking for a type definition that would allow me to get around that

Comment: I don’t see my suggestion involving “casting”.  That term doesn’t apply unambiguously in JS or TS. Could you rephrase ?

Comment: I think you're having trouble because there is no single type that behaves the way you want: you need to produce values that act like both types but accept values that act like either type. That implies you might need an "in" type and an "out" type like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WvQVYm) shows.  Does that work for you?   If so I could write that as an answer.  If not, I'm thinking the answer is going to look like "this is impossible to do with types because it's not type safe".  Let me know how you'd like to proceed.